# Symbol cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

Android Java project, minimal code to reproduce the problem:

`Constants.java`:

```
package alex.restaurantfinder;

public class Constants {
    public static final String LOGTAG = "...";
}
```

`ReviewCriteria.java`:

```
package alex.restaurantfinder;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ReviewCriteria extends Activity {
    static String s = Constants.LOGTAG;            // error
}
```

Error message:

> Constants.LOGTAG cannot be resolved.

Where is my error?

**Edit**.
The problem was, when I pressed Ctrl+Shft+O in Eclipse, it added this line:

```
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
```

It prevented compiler to work with my own Constants class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there might be another Class called `Constants` that is imported automatically.

can you try using the fully qualified name `alex.restaurantfinder.Constants.LOGTAG`?

Answer (score 1):

I put the code in eclipse and found no error. It compiled without any problems. May be you can try to clean and recompile once.

Comment: No, it doesn't work with the terminal on Fedora. eclipse uses its own compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `import alex.restaurantfinder.Constants;`

**EDIT:** Sorry, not necessary as classes are in the same package, as said below...

Comment: Its not required for the same package

Comment: Do we need? Since both classes are in the same package..?

Comment: Oops, true, I missed the fact it was in the same package :) edited